Add a thermostat to a gas oven?
Can you add a thermostat to a LP gas oven? I made the mistake of buying one without a thermostat, and the oven runs way hot, even with the temperature knob turned all the way down the temperature is over 400 degrees. What parts would I have to add or replace?

can we know the model you have

"even with the temperature knob turned all the way down" This knob is the thermostat. Your oven is broken. If it ran that way from the beginning, it was broken from the factory. If it is new within the time limits for return, return it and get a new one, or try a different manufacturer. You may also be able to replace the damaged thermostat.

@Triplefault No, the knob is not necessarily a thermostat. It may be a gas control only (just like a stove burner). This seems to be most common in camping and boat ovens (and somewhat rare in home ovens), but it is absolutely a thing that exists.
